# I'm confused, my ListView doesn't work when moving to another activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I wrote this code using many references from the internet, but I don't know why my `ListView` doesn't work when moving to another activity. Can anyone help me to find what the problem is in my code?

This is **UPDATED** `MainActivity`, and I used `Parcelable` to move the data to the `detailActivity`.

```
public class detailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String EXTRA_MOVIE = "extra_movie";

    private TextView tvJudul, tvDurasi, tvGenre,
            tvRilis, tvRate, tvRatecount, tvShortdesc, tvSinopsis;
    private ImageView ivPoster;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

        tvJudul = findViewById(R.id.tvDetailJudul);
        tvDurasi = findViewById(R.id.tvDetailDurasi);
        tvGenre = findViewById(R.id.tvDetailGenre);
        tvRilis = findViewById(R.id.tvDetailRilis);
        tvRate = findViewById(R.id.tvDetailRate);
        tvRatecount = findViewById(R.id.tvDetailRateCount);
        tvShortdesc = findViewById(R.id.tvDetailShortDesc);
        tvSinopsis = findViewById(R.id.tvDetailSinopsis);
        ivPoster = findViewById(R.id.ivDetailPoster);

        Movie movie = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(EXTRA_MOVIE);
        tvJudul.setText(movie.getJudul());
        tvDurasi.setText(movie.getDurasi());
        tvGenre.setText(movie.getGenre());
        tvRilis.setText(movie.getRilis());
        tvRate.setText(movie.getRate());
        tvRatecount.setText(movie.getRatecount());
        tvShortdesc.setText(movie.getShortdesc());
        tvSinopsis.setText(movie.getSinopsis());
    }
}
```

And this is my `detailActivity`. In this class I get the data from the `MainActivity` with `Parcelable`.

```
public class detailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String EXTRA_MOVIE = "extra_movie";

    String dtJudul, dtDurasi, dtGenre, dtRilis,
            dtRate, dtRateCount, dtShortDesc, dtSinopsis, dtPoster;
    ViewHolder holder;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

        Movie movie = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(EXTRA_MOVIE);
        holder.tvJudul.setText(movie.getJudul());
        holder.tvDurasi.setText(movie.getDurasi());
        holder.tvGenre.setText(movie.getGenre());
        holder.tvRilis.setText(movie.getRilis());
        holder.tvRate.setText(movie.getRate());
        holder.tvRatecount.setText(movie.getRatecount());
        holder.tvShortdesc.setText(movie.getShortdesc());
        holder.tvSinopsis.setText(movie.getSinopsis());
    }

    static class ViewHolder{
        private TextView tvJudul, tvDurasi, tvGenre,
                tvRilis, tvRate, tvRatecount, tvShortdesc, tvSinopsis;
        private ImageView ivPoster;

        void ViewHolder(View view){
            tvJudul = view.findViewById(R.id.tvDetailJudul);
            tvDurasi = view.findViewById(R.id.tvDetailDurasi);
            tvGenre = view.findViewById(R.id.tvDetailGenre);
            tvRilis = view.findViewById(R.id.tvDetailRilis);
            tvRate = view.findViewById(R.id.tvDetailRate);
            tvRatecount = view.findViewById(R.id.tvDetailRateCount);
            tvShortdesc = view.findViewById(R.id.tvDetailShortDesc);
            tvSinopsis = view.findViewById(R.id.tvDetailSinopsis);
            ivPoster = view.findViewById(R.id.ivDetailPoster);
        }
    }
}
```

This is `MovieAdapter`

```
public class MovieAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    //private final Context context;
    private ArrayList<Movie> listMovie;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    public MovieAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Movie> listMovie){
        this.listMovie = listMovie;
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public void setMovies(ArrayList<Movie> movies ) {
        this.listMovie = movies;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listMovie.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return listMovie.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if(view == null){
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_movie, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.ViewHolder(view);
            view.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }
        Glide.with(viewGroup.getContext())
                .load(listMovie.get(position).getPoster())
                .apply(new RequestOptions().centerCrop())
                .into(holder.ivPoster);

        holder.tvJudul.setText(listMovie.get(position).getJudul());
        holder.tvDurasi.setText(listMovie.get(position).getDurasi());
        holder.tvGenre.setText(listMovie.get(position).getGenre());
        holder.tvRilis.setText(listMovie.get(position).getRilis());
        holder.tvRate.setText(listMovie.get(position).getRate());
        holder.tvRatecount.setText(listMovie.get(position).getRatecount());
        holder.tvShortdesc.setText(listMovie.get(position).getShortdesc());
        return view;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        private TextView tvJudul, tvDurasi, tvGenre,
                tvRilis, tvRate, tvRatecount, tvShortdesc, tvSinopsis;
        private ImageView ivPoster;

        void ViewHolder(View view){
            tvJudul = view.findViewById(R.id.tvItemJudul);
            tvDurasi = view.findViewById(R.id.tvItemDurasi);
            tvGenre = view.findViewById(R.id.tvItemGenre);
            tvRilis = view.findViewById(R.id.tvItemRilis);
            tvRate = view.findViewById(R.id.tvItemRate);
            tvRatecount = view.findViewById(R.id.tvItemRateCount);
            tvShortdesc = view.findViewById(R.id.tvItemShortDesc);
            ivPoster = view.findViewById(R.id.ivPItemPoster);
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me fix it. I've already searched the internet and tried many things, but nothing worked. This is the notification in logcat when I click the `ListView`.

```
D/ViewRootImpl@82b704[MainActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@82b704[MainActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 1
D/AbsListView: onTouchUp() mTouchMode : 0
```

Thank you so much for your response.

Comment: How exactly is it not working? Is it crashing? Is it just not opening `detailActivity`? Something else?

Comment: nothing happen when i clicked item on listview. And in logcat there is information like this and i don't know that means

D/ViewRootImpl@82b704[MainActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 0

D/ViewRootImpl@82b704[MainActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 1

D/AbsListView: onTouchUp() mTouchMode : 0

Comment: You posted `detailActivity` again. Anyhoo, if nothing is happening when you click on a list item in `MainActivity`, the first thing I would check is the layout you're using in `MovieAdapter`. Certain `View`s will prevent an `OnItemClickListener` from firing, by default. As Oleg Gryb mentions below, if `detailActivity` were to actually open, it should be crashing with a `NullPointerException`, with the given code.

Comment: i have updated MovieAdapter

Comment: I meant the layout, `item_movie.xml`. Please look into how to put together a [mcve]. When you've assembled one, you will know exactly what needs to be included in the question, and what you can leave out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just by looking at this code, it's not supposed to work. If detailActivity activity starts, it should immediately crash with NPE since holder variable was not initialized anywhere. There is no any code that would call ViewHolder(view) constructor.

> Java does not have uninitialized variables. Fields of classes and objects that do not have an explicit initializer and elements of arrays are automatically initialized with the default value for their type (false for boolean, 0 for all numerical types, **null for all reference types**).

Either you don't show the whole code or this is not supposed to work.

Comment: i just wanna to declare that variable, what should i do with the code

Comment: You'll need to learn Java basics, e.g. how to call constructor. In your case there should be code somewhere like: holder = new ViewHolder(view) where view is the one containing all other UI controls that you want to show.  Another thing - you didn't explain what "doesn't work" mean and that's why people downvoting. There maybe other issues as well that prevent the activity from starting. Why don't you use Log.d to check if you even get inside onItemClick?

Comment: I updated MainActivity and it still has errors like this ...

in Logcat
D/ViewRootImpl@82b704[MainActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@82b704[MainActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 1
D/AbsListView: onTouchUp() mTouchMode : 0

Comment: Put Log.d to onItemClick to see if this one is even called. Put Log.d to onCreate in detailActiviy to determine if the activity starts

Comment: the problem finish, i tried moving listener function to MovieAdapter. Thank you